# Form validation with mutiple if/else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm doing form validation using jQuery. I want to validate the complete form using an if/else condition and I don't want to use any plugin. For example:

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    //validation here all form fields   
});
```

I want to write in a condition like depend on `type` of attribute text, email and so on.
My question is can anyone suggest me how to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(#submit_form).on('click', function(){
  //validate here
});

});
```

```css
.success_msg {
    width: 350px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}
.iva-nav {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: all 0.74s ease;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.iva-nav span {
 transform: translateZ(8px);
 -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.iva-nav:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 50;
}
.iva-nav:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 25;
}
.iva-nav:hover:before {
 transform: rotate(225deg);
 background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);

}
.iva-nav:hover:after {
 transform: rotate(133deg);
 background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}
.fancy-heading-s1 {
 max-width: 1400px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 25px 0;
 color: #ffffff;
} 
.fancy-heading-s2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 color: #fff;
}
.fancy-title {
 display: block;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.cfar-s1 .cfar-heading {
 text-align: center;
}

*:focus{ outline: none;}

.cfar {
 max-width: 1140px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cfar-s1 {
 padding: 40px 100px;
 background-color: #313439;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:after {
 content: " . ";
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transform: translateY(-15%);
 margin: 0 10px;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:last-child:after {
 content: "";
 margin-right: 0;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 {
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 span {
 color: #da4e5b;
}
.cfar-s1 form {
 padding: 30px 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.cfar .detail {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px 0;
 flex-basis: 48%;
}

.cfar .detail input,.detail textarea,.detail select {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 5px 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.cfar option { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }
.cfar .detail textarea {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 resize: none;
}

.cfar .detail label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}
.cfar .detail input:focus:after,.detail textarea:foucs:after,.detail select:focus:after,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:before, 
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 0;
 background: red;
 height: 2px;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:after { right: 50%;}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:before { left: 50%;}

.cfar .detail input:focus ~ label,
.cfar .detail input:valid ~ label,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ label,
.cfar .detail textarea:valid ~ label {
 top: -20px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:after,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:after 
.cfar .detail select:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail select:focus ~ .inputBar:after {
 width: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .answer { 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 114px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 left: 133px;
 position: inherit;
}
/* custom css*/
span.error{
 /*display: none;*/
 color: red;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px !important;
 right: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}  
.error_show {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
 color: red;
}
input:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: none;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------
  contact form style 1
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.cfar-s1 .detail input,.cfar-s1 .detail textarea,.cfar-s1 .detail select {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar {
 position: relative;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar:before {
 content: "";
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: -1px;
 background-color: #ff0000;
 width: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar-s1 .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:before {
 width: 100%;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail label {
 top: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #777777;
}
.message {
 flex-basis: 100% !important;
}
.btn-container {
 margin: 40px auto;
}
.btn-container .btn {
 border: none;
 background-color: #da4e5b;
 padding: 20px 75px;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactform1">
    <div id="note"></div>
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
        <div id="note"></div>
        <div class="detail">
            <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
            <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
            <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
            <span class="error">This field is required</span>
            </div><!--detail-->
            <div class="detail">
                <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
                <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
                <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
                <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
                </div><!--detail-->
                <div class="detail">
                    <input type="number" autocomplete="off" name="phone" required />
                    <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
                    <label for="contact_phone">Phone Number</label>
                    <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
                    </div><!--detail-->
                    <div class="detail">
                        <input type="text"  autocomplete="off" name="enquiry" required />
                        <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
                        <label for="contact_enquiry">I want to know about...</label>
                        <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                        </div><!--detail-->
                        <div class="detail message">
                            <textarea type="text"  autocomplete="off" name="message" required></textarea>
                            <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
                            <label for="contact_message">Type your Message here</label>
                            <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                            </div><!--detail-->
                            <div class="detail">
                                <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
                                <input type="radio"  name="male" required />Male
                                <input type="radio"  name="female" required />Female
                                <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                                </div><!--detail-->
                                
                                <div class="detail">
                                    <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
                                    <input type="checkbox"  name="html" required />HTMl
                                    <input type="checkbox"  name="css" required />CSS
                                    <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                                    </div><!--detail-->
                                    <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form">
                                        <a href="#">Submit</a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Suggest you a way to write an `if` condition...?

Comment: On submit create a temp object with your form field and create an extra function which only validates your object.

Comment: @Husna yes To the all fields where i have to write conditions.

Comment: **Suggest:** google => How to validate a form input by jQuery

Comment: @Ravi Sapariya i want to use jquery only.

Comment: @Husna yes you can use it as i suggest.

Comment: Give us an example of one of your form fields and what input your are expecting.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://formden.com/blog/validate-contact-form-jquery

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I edited my question check.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```js
$('.submit').click(function(){
    if($("#form_id").valid()){
      return true
    }else{
      alert(" Enter Valid Data");
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: according to my code how should I do. I want to use `typeof` and validate all text field.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Fiddle.

[1. Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justinae/qZrgS/)

[2. Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chadkuehn/uxqgytnw/)

For Example

```
        var userName = $("input[name=userName]").val();
        var subject = $("input[name=subject]").val();
        var message = $("input[name=message]").val();
        if (/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/.test(userName)) {
             alert("Your name is in the correct format");
        }
        else{
            alert("Your name can't contain numbers or other characters etc.");
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this strategy to validate your form.

```
function submitObject(){
        var object = {};
        object.name = $(".name").val();
        object.email = $(".email").val();
        try{
          if(this.validateForm(object )){
             // call AJAX to save data.
           }
        }catch(error){
          // show error message
       }
    } 

    function validateForm(object) {
       if(this.isEmpty(object.name)){
         throw "Parameter is not a null or empty!";
        }
       if(this.isEmpty(object.email)){
         throw "Parameter is not a null or empty!";
      }
    return true;
    }



 function isEmpty(str) {
     return (!str || 0 === str.length);
   }
```